# div within li not coming as block i.e one below other

Tags: html, css

In my code below i have li within which i have divs which i want to show as one below that other so each li has name below which is the image below which the link but they seem to align side by side instead

```
<article id="container">
<?php
$arg= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'products', 'numberposts' => -1)); 
?>

 <ul id="Content">     
    <?php foreach ( $arg as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
        if (!empty($post)){                 
    ?>  
        <li class="pindex">
            <div class="pname"><a href="<?php get_field('url',$post);?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <div class="pimg"><a href="<?php get_field('url',$post);?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('')?></a></div>
            <div class="plink"><a href="<?php get_field('url',$post);?>">CLICK HERE</a></div>
        </li>               
    <?php } endforeach; ?>    
    </ul>
</article>
```

style.css

```
#container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

#Content {
   -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
     width: auto;
     height:auto;     
}

#Content li.index {
 width: auto;
 height:auto; 
display:block;
position:relative;
}


#Content .pindex .pname, #Content .pindex .pname a{ 
width: auto;
height:auto;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
display:block;
position:relative;
}

#Content .pindex .pimg img , #Content .pindex .pimg img a{      
   width: auto;
   height:auto;
   display:block;
   position:relative;
}

#Content .plink, #Content .plink a{ 
width:auto;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
```

Comment: if you can post a fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your column properties. I haven't really used this property before but it seems to be cascading down to the content of the list items. (Although it does seem to work correctly if you have an exact multiple of four list items.) Removing this code:

```
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 10px;
```

will allow all the elements to flow normally (on top of each other). If you want to have the posts displayed in columns of 4 add `width: 25%; float: left;` to `#Content li.pindex`. Please note you are missing a p from the pindex class in your css. This method has the added benefit of working in older ie versions as well.

Edit:
I looked up about the column property and it seems you are missing the width of the columns.

```
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-width: 100px;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;

-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-width: 100px;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;

column-count: 4;
column-width: 100px;
column-gap: 10px;
```

Adding that also fixes the issue without the need for a float, but is not supported in IE 8 and 9 so up to you.